# Java: Getting multiple lines from socket

Tags: java, sockets, line

I have a Java application that consists of a client and a server. The client sends encrypted commands to the server, and the server executes them.

The problem that I am having right now is that, with my encryption algorithm, sometimes the encrypted command contains "\n" or "\r" characters, which mess up my server code. This is because I am using the readLine() method, which stops when it finds a line terminator. What I need is a way to read all the characters the client sends into one string.

Here is my code:

```
public void run(){            
        System.out.println("Accepted Client!");

        try{                                
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "ISO8859_1"));
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), "ISO8859_1"));

            String clientCommand = null;

            while(RunThread){                    
                // read incoming stream
                do{
                    clientCommand = in.readLine();
                }while(clientCommand == null);

                //decrypt the data
                System.out.println("Client: " + clientCommand);

                if(clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
                    RunThread = false;
                }else{
                    //do something
                    out.flush();
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

Everything I've tried (various forms of nested loops using the read() function) hasn't worked. I would welcome any help or suggestions. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Simply do not use text, Reader/Writer, but Input/OutputStream, and read binary data (bytes). In the code above the encoding can play havoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see encryption in the code you posted, but usually it's not a good idea to rely on separator characters.

When sending binary data, you should prepend the length of the data to the stream, and then you know exactly how many bytes to expect (and when the message will end.) It's more efficient to do things that way too instead of looking for a newline character.

Comment: Thanks! So how would you go about doing it in terms of code? I guess my real struggle here is how the waiting and receiving should work. I either end up in an infinite loop or I don't receive anything. How can I tell when data is coming in, and how can I count out how far to read?

Comment: @Jason Basically, your loop would call read() to get a char containing the length of the message (blocking until a message is available.) You can then call read again using that length to read the message into a byte array. From there you can decrypt it or convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
// read incoming stream
do{
    clientCommand = in.readLine();
}while(clientCommand == null);
```

That == null seems wrong

Try

```
String line = null;
do {
    line = in.readLine ();
    clientCommand += line
} while (line != null);
```

Comment: That code seems as though it would work to a point, except that I would lose any newline or return characters. I need all the characters in order to decrypt my string, and simple appending a "\n" wouldn't work because it originally might have been a "\r\n" or even an "\r". . .

Answer (score 0):

One thing you must do, when working with TCP/IP, is to send the message length before the actual message. The application level cannot foresee the package size the TCP level is delivering to the destiny. So, before your message, you have to send a header with the message size and the destiny would read just these bytes.
About `readLine()`, I think it's better use another approaches like streams. Shortly, one suggestion:

```
    Socket oSocket = new Socket(sAddress, iPort);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(oSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oSocket.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: 'Tis a great suggestion; but still, I'm lost. What would be the logistics behind actually receiving the data into a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
  clientCommand = in.readLine();
} while(clientCommand == null);
```

This makes no sense. `readLine()` only returns `null` at end of stream, so you are telling Java to loop infinitely at end of stream. I don't even understand why there is a loop at all. You don't want to ignore any input from the client, you want to process it all. You should read one line from the client, execute it, and read another line. Repeat until `null`, then close the socket.